# file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, loops

I want to list 10.000 pages in the screen using php function `file_get_contents` to get information for a db.

This works until about page 500, then the script stops running (the page has loaded) and displays no error.

```
<?php

for ($nr=1; $nr<=10000; $nr++){

$url = "http://site.com/u$nr";
$string = file_get_contents($url);

echo '<textarea>'.$string.'</textarea>';

}

?>
```

@edit

I want to get this information for my computer to be manipulated via Javascript, I think that gives a lot of work to manipulate HTML using PHP.
Record these pages in db is a good idea.

Comment: I think your (max_execution_time) for PHP will end...

Comment: "to get information for a db" ?? what do you mean by that? why don't you write a script that reads in the data and throws it directly into the DB rather than into textboxes? speaking of which, you should be html_special_char-ing that `$string`.

Comment: It's possible that your browser hangs because of too many textareas are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advice to set your time_limit *inside* the loop. Setting the time-limit will 'extend' timeout with the given amount of time;

```
<?php 
for ($nr=1; $nr<=10000; $nr++){
    $url = "http://site.com/u$nr";
    $string = file_get_contents($url);
    echo '<textarea>'.$string.'</textarea>';

    // extend the time-limit with this amount of time,
    // the amount of time this request is allowed to take
    set_time_limit(5);
}

?>
```

This way you won't have to calculate the 'total' time limit for 10.000 records, and don't allow a *single* request to take (for example) 1 hour to complete

**[update]**
New information posted by the OP states that he wants to process the inputs using javascript. Therefore, a better solution will be to fetch all pages 1 at a time using jQuery, process the information and submit the results to the database, using a Ajax post and server-side saving it to the database

Answer (score 1):

Check your error logs. Your script has probably timed out (the default is 30 seconds). Try setting a larger timeout using http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

`set_time_limit(120); // Script may run for 120 seconds before timing out`

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script is timing out. Default maximum execution time is 30 seconds. Use this function

[set_time_limt](http://php.net/set_time_limit)

By the way loading 10,000 pages will take quite some ( time + bandwidth + resources ) and might bog things down

Answer (score 0):

You probably run out of memory/execution time.

You need to check `phpinfo()` and check the appropriate settings (`memory_limit` should be higher than `256M`, `max_execution_time` should also be more than 30 minutes, if you intend to use your server for this kind of operations).

Also, make sure you log your errors, and you display them (in development environment) ( `display_errors = 1` , `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, `log_errors = 1` ).

Grabbing 10000 pages is a resource consuming process, you may want to consider storing some information in the database.

Edit: As people before me said, `set_time_limit()` is the 'per script' option of the `max_execution_time`, use it if you don't want to permanently change the server execution time.